# JSON in java by POST getting None return

Tags: java, python, json, post

I request POST by this code

```
                    URL url = new URL("adress/discordnotifi");

                    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                    httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(5000);

                    httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(5000);

                    httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    httpURLConnection.connect();
                    JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
                    myPWord = ((EditText) (findViewById(R.id.edit_Id))).getText().toString();
                    object.put("token", tokens);
                    object.put("discordid", mydiscord);

                    OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                    outputStream.write(object.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));

                    Log.d("debug",object.toString());
                    outputStream.flush();
                    outputStream.close();
```

and my **tokens** and **mydiscord** is the information that I want to send as JSON format like
`{"token":"tokens","discordid":"mydiscord"}`

and from python flask

```
@app.route('/discordnotifi', methods=['POST'])
def post():
    content = request.json
    print(content)
    Discordid = int(content["discordid"])
    token = content['token']
    """Discordid = request.form.get("discordid")
    token = request.form.get("token")"""
    print(Discordid, token)
    return ("Thx")
```

at print(content) I get **None** I really don't know whts wrong here. I was planning to send Json with information but I getting None from Json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very least you're missing is enabling output on the connection. Add:

```
httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
```

The server may also require that you set some headers, for example `content-type` to tell it that you are sending JSON.

```
httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; utf-8");
```

If you can use Java 11, consider using the new [HttpClient](https://openjdk.java.net/groups/net/httpclient/intro.html) class instead of HttpUrlConnection. It simplifies creating correct requests.